# Asking for a criticism on GIS viewsheds?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is GIS Stack Exchange a good place to ask for the pros and cons of the viewsheds analysis compared to a subject personally climbing the hill and writing his observations? Or is it a discussion topic for another forum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The GIS Stack Exchange Main site is not designed for discussions.

It is a focussed Question and Answer site.

Such a discussion would be suitable for our GIS Chat Room.

Alternatively, you could think more about the discussion you were planning, and try to distill a focussed question from it.  I think that is usually possible, but not always easy, to do.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have enough rep for the GIS Chat Room (I'm nearly there!) so I tried reformulating the question.

Comment: From what I can tell you had at least 80 rep prior to asking this question, and the [Talk in Chat privilege](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) only needs 20.

Answer (score 8):

It could be on topic if it avoided two of our current closing reasons:

Too broad:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Primarily opinion-based:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

The question would need to be clear, having a specific question which would be answerable in a objective and technical fashion.

For more help about on topic subjects in GIS Stack Exchange, refer to our [help center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.